# Javascript: creating new column in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like so:

```
var arr1 = [
    {"Date": "2017-04-15", "Price":"300"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-16", "Price":"310"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-17", "Price":"320"},
]
```

I wish to add a new key(`newDate`)-value(JS `Date` object) pair in each row. That is, I want to end up with:

```
[
    {"newDate":2017-04-14T14:00:00.000Z, "Date": "2017-04-15", "Price":"300"},
    {"newDate":2017-04-15T14:00:00.000Z, "Date": "2017-04-16", "Price":"310"},
    {"newDate":2017-04-16T14:00:00.000Z, "Date": "2017-04-17", "Price":"320"},
]
```

My script so far, which I run in `node`:

```
function getDateObject(dateString) {
    // Splits a yyyy-mm-dd string, and returns a Date object
    var parts = dateString.split("-")
    var myDate = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2])
    return myDate


for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr1[i])
    arr1[i]["newDate"] = getDateObject(arr1[i]["Date"])
}
```

This gives an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at getDateObject
```

That is, it's throwing at error at the line: `var parts = dateString.split("-")`. I'm puzzled by this syntax error because of course `dateString` is not defined; it's meant to be an input parameter, rather than a variable instantiated by `var`, `let` or `const` or something. Am I missing something?

Bonus: would be great if someone could suggest a way to do this with `array.map`.

Comment: What are you actually passing to your function?

Comment: @PM77-1 He's passing `getDateObject(arr1[i][0])` (no `0` property exists on the object)

Comment: @CertainPerformance - It was intended as a *hint*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution using `Array.map()` and `destructuring` could be next one:

```js
var arr1 = [
    {"Date": "2017-04-15", "Price":"300"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-16", "Price":"310"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-17", "Price":"320"},
];

console.log( arr1.map(o => ({newDate: new Date(o.Date), ...o})) );
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or use `Array.forEach()` if you don't mind to change the original `array`:

```js
var arr1 = [
    {"Date": "2017-04-15", "Price":"300"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-16", "Price":"310"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-17", "Price":"320"},
];

arr1.forEach(o => o.newDate = new Date(o.Date));
console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `arr[i]` is has no key `0`. If you want to access the `Date` use [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)
`arr[i].Date` or you can use `arr[i]['Date']`
 
A better way would be to use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var arr1 = [
    {"Date": "2017-04-15", "Price":"300"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-16", "Price":"310"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-17", "Price":"320"},
]
arr1 = arr1.map(obj => (Object.assign(obj,{newDate:new Date(obj.Date)})));
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr1` is an array of objects, not an array of arrays. Referencing `arr1[i][0]` only makes sense if you're trying to get something from the 0th property on the object being iterated over, but no such property exists, thus `undefined`. Pass `arr[i].date` instead:

```js
var arr1 = [
    {"Date": "2017-04-15", "Price":"300"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-16", "Price":"310"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-17", "Price":"320"}
]

function getDateObject(dateString) {
    // Splits a yyyy-mm-dd string, and returns a Date object
    var parts = dateString.split("-")
    var myDate = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2])
    return myDate
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr1[i]["newDate"] = getDateObject(arr1[i].Date)
}
console.log(arr1);
```

Or, with `.map`:

```js
var arr1 = [
  {"Date": "2017-04-15", "Price":"300"},
  {"Date": "2017-04-16", "Price":"310"},
  {"Date": "2017-04-17", "Price":"320"}
];

const arr2 = arr1.map((obj) => {
  const [y, m, d] = obj.Date.split('-');
  return { ...obj, newDate: new Date(y, m - 1, d) };
});
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to access `"Date"` instead of `0` in your for-loop

```
arr1[i]["newDate"] = getDateObject(arr1[i]["Date"])

// or

arr1[i].newDate = getDateObject(arr1[i].Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Date` property of the array object in valid JS date format you can simply use `new Date()` function of JS to create `newDate` property following sinpet is simplest pure JS code

```js
var arr1 = [
    {"Date": "2017-04-15", "Price":"300"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-16", "Price":"310"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-17", "Price":"320"}
]

//adding new date
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
  arr1[i].newDate = new Date(arr1[i].Date);
  
//test
console.log(arr1)
```